# findById not working in mognodb with nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, find

This is my code;
I'm try for update user data. like so you are seen this code. But result coming null.
I'm not understand. please help me guys

```
// @Router UPDATE /updateforslip/:id
// @desc UPDATE update by ID
// @access Private
router.put('/update/user/data/:id', async (req, res) => {

   var update = Pan.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
    $set: req.body
  })
    console.log(update)

      update.exec((error, data) => {
        if (error) throw error;
       res.json(data)
       })
    })
```

Coming result

```
in console.log(update)
null
```

I'm using postman for request.

Comment: In result error = null,
              data = null

Answer (score 0):

Just try like this, don’t use exec() when you want to uae async await
and use try/carch for handling errors

```
try{
 var data = await Pan.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
    $set: req.body
  }).lean();
res.json(data)
},
catch(error){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 router.put('/update/user/data/:id', async (req, res) => {

 tyr{

   var update = await Pan.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {$set: req.body})
   res.json(update)

  }catch (err){
    throw error;
  }
```